# Como destacar um linha no resultado de consulta php + sql

Tags: php, script

Estou desenvolvendo um Aplicativo que usa uma página `PHP`  onde terei um ranking de pontos que o usuário faz ao realizar alguma interação com o mesmo. Tenho um script que gera a lista em ordem (do maior para o menor) mostrando do primeiro colocado até o ultimo.

Porém eu desejo DESTACAR o usuário que faz a consulta, passada através de um formulário (**$usuario =$_GET['usuario'];**), formatando sua linha em Negrito. Acredito ser uma condição IF mas não consigo chegar até a resolução do problema.

> Citação meu código atual, funcionando perfeitamente, porém sem destacar o usuário que faz a consulta.

```
  $usuario =$_GET['usuario'];

   $conexao = mysqli_connect('XXXXXXX','XXXXXX','XXXXXXX');
  mysqli_select_db($conexao,'XXXXXX');

 $sql="select * from login order by pontos DESC";

  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die ("Erro: " . mysqli_error());

$posicao = 1; //variavel

echo  <table width='90%' style='padding:10px;'><tr><td width='20%'><b>Class.</td><td width='60%'><b>Participante</td><td width='20%'><b>Pontos</td>";

//faz um looping e cria um array com os campos da consulta
while($array = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)) {

echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $posicao;   // COLUNA DA POSIÇÃO NO RANKING

echo "</td><td>";

    echo $array->usuario; // AQUI EU QUERO UM IF PARA DIFERENCIAR O USUÁRIO PASSADO LÁ EM CIMA.

echo "</td><td>";
echo $array->pontos; // coluna dos pontos
echo "</td></tr>";
$posicao = $posicao + 1; // acumula próxima posição até terminar
} 

echo "</table>"
```

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português, se você ainda não fez um tour na comunidade, [acesse por aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e saiba como deve elaborar suas perguntas e respostas. A propósito, seu código está com alguns erros de abertura de aspas... provavelmente isso pode estar causando erros no seu script.

Comment: Olá Ivan, obrigado por seu suporte. Como comentei no Post. O código NÃO contém erros, está funcionando perfeitamente, apenas desejo ADICIONAR esta funcionalidade ao mesmo. A possibilidade de, ao se fazer o laço, identificar o usuário no BD e checar se é o mesmo $usuario passado através do $_GET.

Comment: @LeomanAlvesMoitinho Como você é novo aqui, sugiro que veja [ask] e também lhe digo que não é um fórum, portanto você não tem que editar a pergunta com "resolvido" no título, e sim somente marcar a resposta correta. Este site é um Q&A. Seja bem-vindo.

Comment: Agradeço as orientações. Sou novo porque só agora fiz o cadastro, mas uso como aprendizado (bem como milhares de outras pessoas) todas os questionamentos e respostas advindas do site. Recomendo em treinamentos que dou para que os alunos pesquisem em sua vasta biblioteca de conhecimento e compartilhem os resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($array->usuario == $usuario){
   echo '<strong>'.$usuario.'</strong>';
}else
   echo $usuario;
}
```

Comment: Raylan, obrigado por seu suporte. Já havia tentado desta maneira e não funcionou. Não tinha atentado para a sintaxe correta. No seu código faltou apenas abrir a chave depois do else. Obrigado. Vocês podem testar o código e/ou falhas no endereço:  http://festivaldeaplicativos.com/churralcool/mostrapontosposi.php?usuario=Nina

Answer (score 2):

Só como complemento, uma alternativa com operador ternário:

```
echo '</td><td>';
echo $array->usuario == $usuario ? '<strong>'.$usuario.'</strong>' : $usuario;
echo '</td><td>';
```

Não se esqueça de usar `htmlentities($usuario)` no `echo`, caso sejam permitidos caracteres especiais como `< > &` etc no nome.

Comment: Olá Bacco. Como seria esta utilização do htmlentities, basta por este código antes do $usuario em cada vez que ele for inserido no código ? Grato.

Comment: @LeomanAlvesMoitinho só na hora de mandar pra tela. Exemplo no caso acima: `$array->usuario == $usuario ? '<strong>'.htmlentities( $usuario ).'</strong>' : htmlentities( $usuario );` - Note que só colocamos no que é escrito na tela. Na comparação e nas outras partes do código não. `htmlentities()` é só para gerar o HTML correto.